# Add "Edit" link in webform result table

Tags: webforms

In my D7 webform result, table format, the default result table is 
"#, SUBMITTED, USER, IP ADDRESS"

I want to add a "Edit" in "ACTION" column, to make it as 
"#, ACTION, SUBMITTED, USER, IP ADDRESS".

I found the codes in theme_webform function as below.

```
function theme_webform_results_table_header($variables) {
  return array(
    array('data' => t('#'), 'field' => 'sid', 'sort' => 'desc'),
    array('data' => t('Submitted'), 'field' => 'submitted'),
    array('data' => t('User'), 'field' => 'name'),
    array('data' => t('IP Address'), 'field' => 'remote_addr'),
  );
}
```

But it is selecting from database table, which adding a row like below doesn't work

```
    array('data' => t('Action'), 'field' => 'sid/edit'),
```

Is there anyway I can add in the edit link?